# Jest Test function bind

Tags: javascript, jestjs, bind

How can one bind s.th. to the test function executed by jest?

I want to run the same set of tests twice for different configs, like this:

```
function wrap(title, fn) {
    [1,2].forEach(x => {
        this.hello = x
        fn.bind(this)
        fn() // works
        test(title, fn) // does not work
    })
}

wrap('test hello world', function() {
    console.log('this.hello', this.hello)
});
```

But `this` is `undefined` when run by jest.

Comment: you never use `fn.bind(this)` you need an assignment of it.

Comment: @NinaScholz works without assignment

Comment: where do you hand over `this`?

Comment: there's no more than this example in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out jest provides a built-in helper to do exactly this:

```
describe.each([1,2])('test', x => {
    test(`test ${x}`, function() {
        console.log('x', x)
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
HTML CODE : 

<!-- createNewAbout is my module name and submitAboutContent is the Controller You you can call it the backend function .
```

You Can Use URL in Form Action too.  -->
    
    
    
    
    Enter Title
    
    
    
    Enter Description
    
    
    
    Add Image
    
    
    
    Submit

```
<!-- this is the function Which i am Calling . I am taking value of  name attribute of button to disable button for multiple fuction call and also taking an array of values of name attribute of  manditory fields. Here we cant use values of ID attribute so we have to use name . -->
<script> 
function validationOnlySubmitForm(button_name="", arr="") {
var fields = arr, flag  = 0;
document.getElementsByName(button_name)[0].setAttribute("disabled" , true);
for (var i = 0 ; i <= fields.length - 1 ; i++) {
if (document.getElementsByName(fields[i])[0].value.length == 0) {
flag = 1;
document.getElementsByName(fields[i])[0].focus();
alert(fields[i] + " is manditory.");
document.getElementsByName(button_name)[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
return false;
}
}

if (flag == 0)
return true;
}

</script>
```